# merging two tables and correcting the strings in python

Tags: python, merge

Relatively new to Python. I have two csv files with two columns each, and I am trying to merge them and create one file.

so, say, they are:
**Table1**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzMMY.jpg)

**Table2**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zggxy.png)

I'm trying to write a code to merge the two tables into one, such that:

1. A country is only entered twice if the description is different in both tables
2. Table 1 is the master list, or table, and the code will check the description and and if the description in table1 is very close to table2, except for a few words or letters, then it will take that of table1.
3. The country name should be entered for as many descriptions as are available in the two tables

One of the problems I'm having is that the text in the description cannot be out in a dictionary.

This is the code I have tried so far, and it did not work well:

```
import csv

file1 = open('dataset.csv', 'rb') 
file2 = open('dataset2.csv', 'rb') 
data_a = csv.reader(file1)
data_b = dict(csv.reader(file2))  # <-- dict
file3 =  open('out.csv', 'wb') 

csv_out = csv.writer(file3)
for country, description in data_a:
csv_out.writerow([country, description, data_b.get(country, '')])
```

Comment: Can you post the tables rather than images?

Comment: can you use external librairies?? pleas add text from your csv and check pandas

Answer (score 0):

I do get a result using ur code, after changing the writemode from 'rb' to 'r+'.

As input I used:

table_a = India, Orange is the new black

table_b = India, Blue street

As a result I get:

csv_out = India, Orange is the new black, Blue street

Since you did not specify, I don't know if that is what you wanted to achieve, but changing the write mode, definitly rids you of one of ur problems.

```
import csv
main_table = open('set1.csv', 'r+')
minor_table = open('set2.csv', 'r+')
main_table = csv.reader(main_table)
minor_table = dict(csv.reader(minor_table))
solution_file = open('out.csv', 'r+')
out = csv.writer(soultion_files)
for country, description in main_table:
out.writerow([country, description, minor_table.get(country, '')])
```